# How to position buttons under one another in javascript bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap to build my interface. I currently have 3 buttons, but they are positioned in a row. What I want to happen is have them under one another. How do I achieve that?

Here's the code for the buttons:

```
    this.buttonOne = document.createElement("button");
    this.buttonOne .className = "btn btn-primary";
    this.buttonOne .innerHTML = "Create One";
    this.buttonTwo = document.createElement("button");
    this.buttonTwo .className = "btn btn-default";
    this.buttonTwo .innerHTML = "Create Two";
    this.buttonThree = document.createElement("button");
    this.buttonThree .className = "btn btn-default";
    this.buttonThree .innerHTML = "Create Three";
```

Comment: Why don't put them in a <ul></ul> ?

Answer (score 5):

If you want a `btn-group` you can use `<div class="btn-group-vertical"></div>` and put your buttons in there.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the class `btn-block` to your buttons

http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/base-css.html#buttons

Comment: @BeatAlex I do not want them to take up all the space of the div container that they are in

Comment: Sorry Then you should use the Aditya answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Please try

**display:block;**

> .block_button{
>
> ```
>    display:block;
>
> }
> ```
>
> this.buttonOne .className = "btn btn-primary block_button";